Object is not passed properly to sheet
I have SwiftUI view which looks like this
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
@Query(sort: \Activity.dateOfLastCompletion, order: .reverse) private var activities: [Activity]

@State private var isModalWithDetailsShown = false
@State private var isNewActivitySheetShown = false

@State var selectedActivity: Activity? = nil

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            if activities.isEmpty {
                ContentUnavailableView("No activities", systemImage: "mug.fill", description: Text("Use the plus button to start tracking your first activity"))
            } else {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem()], spacing: 16) {
                        ForEach(activities, id: \.id) { activity in
                            ActivityRow(activity: activity)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selectedActivity = activity
                                    isModalWithDetailsShown = true
                                }
                                .tag(activity as Activity?)
                                .sheet(isPresented: $isModalWithDetailsShown, onDismiss: {
                                    selectedActivity = nil
                                }) {
                                    if let selectedActivity = selectedActivity {
                                        ModalActivityDetailView(activity: selectedActivity)
                                            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.20), .fraction(1)])
                                            .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }.scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Activities")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button(action: { print("User went to settings") }) {
                    Text("Settings")
                }
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    isNewActivitySheetShown.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $isNewActivitySheetShown) {
                    NewAcitivityView()
                }
            }
        }.tint(.primary)
    }
}

When I click on the ActivityRow first time, no matter which SwiftData object, then it opens me an empty sheet with full size. After second click it works properly, and every another one works well too. What's the issue here?

Use sheet(item: $selectedActivity) instead

Also move the sheet out of the ForEach
